# fdisk delete mounted partition

Tags: fdisk

What kinds of problems will occur by deleting partitions with fdisk that are currently mounted. I tested this on a mounted usb partition and it gave me some peculiar errors. I know it is something you shouldn't do, just curious as to why.

Comment: I mean using fdisk to delete a partition that is currently mounted.

Comment: On second reading of your original question, I understood what you we trying to do and deleted my comment. But with your edit there is less change of a human parser error.

Comment: If my memmory serves me well, if you do that when you write changes and exit `fdisk` it will warn you that no changes will take effect until you unmount the drive.

Answer (score 1):

Initially you might not notice anything as the kernel does not necessarily notice changes in the partition table. That is why you get prompted by `fdisk` that you have to reboot the system e.g. if you changed the partitions on the disc you booted from (you can however notify the kernel with a program of that).

If the in (kernel-)memory and on disc partition layouts do not correspond the kernel happily writes where it probably would not be able to read after a reboot and reread of the partition information.